# Modifying a subset sums recursive algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

Currently, I have the following recursive algorithm to solve the subset sum problem. It checks whether any combination of elements in a given vector sum up to a target number. For example, If `A= {1,2,3,4,5}` and `target = 8`, then it should return `true` as `1+2+5=8`. Currently it works perfectly. However I want to make one change to it. I assign values to one of the function parameters in my main and I'm trying to not do that. All I want to do is call the function in my main. Not sure how I would attempt doing that. Any help is appreciated!!

```
bool subsetsum_imp(vector<int> & vec, int n, int sum) {

    if (sum == 0) {
        return true;
    }

    if (n == 0 && sum != 0) {
        return false;
    }

    if (vec[n-1] > sum)     
        return subsetsum_imp(vec, n-1, sum); 

    return subsetsum_imp(vec, n-1, sum) || subsetsum_imp(vec, n-1, sum-vec[n-1]);
}
```

The value n is assigned in my main as follows or else the algorithm doesn't work, How can I incorporate this into my function somehow so I don't have to write it in my main?

```
int n = sizeof(vec)/sizeof(vec[0]);
```

Comment: why not to use vec.size()?

Comment: @SHR It totally slipped my mind to use vec.size(), however will it make a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a wrapper function that calls the recursive function.  Something like:

```
bool subsetsum( vector<int> & vec, int sum )
{
    return subsetsum_imp( vec, vec.size(), sum );
}
```